# Get single item with particular value on hasMany relation Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have two tables:

```
items (
    id
    name
    description
)

images (
    id
    item_id
    number     // 0 -> main image ; 1,2,3,4 ...  -> gallery_image
)
```

with this basic relation:

```
#Item.php

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Image');
}
```

And

```
#Image.php

public function item()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Item');
}
```

To show in my index.php all items with main image I want to get **all items** and the relations, but the relations only when "number" equals to "0" (main image).

If a use:

```
$all = $this->item->get();
foreach ($all as $one) {
        var_dump ($one->images);
}
```

Then I get all items (perfect) and also all images of each item. But I want a collection with all items and one image per item.

What is the best method?

Thanks.

Comment: This is what you need http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/ - use `orderBy('number', 'asc')` on the relation

Comment: perfect! thanks

public function main_image()
    {
        $this->hasOne('Image')->orderBy('number', 'asc')->latest();
    }

Comment: Accept the answer in order to help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use 'helper' relation `hasOne`.

It lets you eager load that single related model:

```
// Use camelCase name, otherwise dynamic property won't work
public function mainImage()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Image')
    ->orderBy('number', 'asc'); 
    // or:      
    // ->where('number', 0);
}
```

Then you can use it and eager load it as given below:

```
$item->mainImage->number; // 0

$items = Item::with('mainImage')->get();
```